# Monday Morning Cryptic Crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

Nothing special, just a cryptic crossword. Hope you enjoy!

[image: Grid]

**ACROSS**
**1** Small stones accent trail border (6)
**4** Deceitful spouse breaks down and admits beginnings of cheating and infidelity (8)
**10** Minnesota hockey player's explosive rant about short shift (5,4)
**11** Fabled Cowboy Bill DuPree finally collared by corrupt cops (5)
**12** The French, before '45, embraced a leader before de Gaulle (5)
**13** Hormonal teen shedding top layers, drunk on cider (9)
**14** Officer leaves cover on broken desert to find unit (7)
**16** Fill up with Indonesian street food (4)
**19** Sub captain ascending to get update from Oracle? (4)
**21** Rattles left 90% annihilated in capital (7)
**24** Stack integrates free Penpa as a sign of goodwill (9)
**25** Drag his butt out of wild Nassau hot spot? (5)
**26** Smoother after abrading, left merely coarse? (5)
**27** In r-values, variation is widespread (9)
**28** Doctor repaints storage rooms (8)
**29** Set up to catch awesome breezes (6)

**DOWN**
**1** Nervous group to keep quiet, circling napping apex predator (8)
**2** Sub-Saharan native of Africa evacuated right before five in the night (8)
**3** Mrs. Kennedy said to be drinking alcohol (5)
**5** Displays new drapes on atrium entrance (7)
**6** CIA contrived to infiltrate Guard to find where charge is held (9)
**7** Mixed choir donned cap with purple flower (6)
**8** Add support to strengthen header; rest will be adjusted after initial installation (6)
**9** Be there at the start and finish (6)
**15** Wheeling Mayor West composes novel (3,6)
**17** Damned dogs got into rank, fetid bottom (8)
**18** An old sailor's canted from violent blows (8)
**20** Up-rising in Boston region repeatedly absorbs the Crown in movement about the Mystic? (7)
**21** Priest is ill-tempered after Hawai'ian Don departed (6)
**22** Expenditure for maintenance paid initially after currency, about a thousand, was unstrapped (6)
**23** Painter needs bonded apprentice (6)
**25** Fallen trees causing change in route (5)

**TEXT VERSION**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|1  |   |2  |   |3  |   |███|4  |5  |   |6  |   |7  |   |8  |
|   |███|   |███|   |███|9  |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |
|10 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |███|11 |   |   |   |   |
|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |
|12 |   |   |   |   |███|13 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |███|   |███|███|███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |
|14 |   |   |   |15 |   |   |███|16 |   |   |   |███|███|███|
|   |███|   |███|   |███|███|███|███|███|   |███|17 |███|18 |
|███|███|███|19 |   |   |20 |███|21 |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|22 |███|23 |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|███|███|   |███|   |
|24 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |███|25 |   |   |   |   |
|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |
|26 |   |   |   |   |███|27 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |███|   |
|28 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |███|29 |   |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finished grid

> [image]

ACROSS

> 1 Small stones accent trail border (6) – **GRAVE+_L**
>  4 Deceitful spouse breaks down and admits beginnings of cheating and infidelity (8) – **SPE(C_+I_)OUS***
>  10 Minnesota hockey player's explosive rant about short shift (5,4) – **N(ORTHS*)TAR***
>  11 Fabled Cowboy Bill DuPree finally collared by corrupt cops (5) – **P(_E)COS***
>  12 The French, before '45, embraced a leader before de Gaulle (5) – **[LA+V(A)L](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Laval)**
>  13 Hormonal teen shedding top layers, drunk on cider (9) – **_EN+DOCRINE***
>  14 Officer leaves cover on broken desert to find unit (7) – **O_+ERSTED***
>  16 Fill up with Indonesian street food (4) – **[SATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satay) ddef**
>  19 Sub captain ascending to get update from Oracle? (4) – **OMEN<**
>  21 Rattles left 90% annihilated in capital (7) – **(m > C)ARACAS** (1000 reduced by 90% in Roman numerals)
>  24 Stack integrates free Penpa as a sign of goodwill (9) – **PI(NEAPP*)LE**
>  25 Drag his butt out of wild Nassau hot spot? (5) – **SAUNA(-s)***
>  26 Smoother after abrading, left merely coarse? (5) – **EMERY(-l)***
>  27 In r-values, variation is widespread (9) – **UNIVERSAL***
>  28 Doctor repaints storage rooms (8) – **PANTRIES***
>  29 Set up to catch awesome breezes (6) – **T(RAD)ES<**

DOWN

> 1 Nervous group to keep quiet, circling napping apex predator (8) – **GA(N_)G+LION**
>  2 Sub-Saharan native of Africa evacuated right before five in the night (8) – **A_A+R+D(V)ARK**
>  3 Mrs. Kennedy said to be drinking alcohol (5) – **ETHYL ~[ethel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethel_Kennedy)**
>  5 Displays new drapes on atrium entrance (7) – **P(A_)RADES***
>  6 CIA contrived to infiltrate Guard to find where charge is held (9) – **CAP(ACI*)TOR**
>  7 Mixed choir donned cap with purple flower (6) – **ORCHI*+D_**
>  8 Add support to strengthen header; rest will be adjusted after initial installation (6) – **S_+I_+STER*** (as a verb, this is a construction term meaning "[add support to](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sister#Verb)")
>  9 Be there at the start and finish (6) – **AT+T_+END**
>  15 Wheeling Mayor West composes novel (3,6) – **TOMSAWYER***
>  17 Damned dogs got into rank, fetid bottom (8) – **AC(CURS)E+_D**
>  18 An old sailor's canted from violent blows (8) – **ASSAULTS ~a salt's**
>  20 Up-rising in Boston region repeatedly absorbs the Crown in movement about the Mystic? (7) – **NE(P(_T)U<)NE** (one movement of *[The Planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Planets)*)
>  21 Priest is ill-tempered after Hawai'ian Don departed (6) – **C(-ho)LERIC**
>  22 Expenditure for maintenance paid initially after currency, about a thousand, was unstrapped (6) – **(-r)UP(K)EE+P_**
>  23 Painter needs bonded apprentice (6) – **_INTER N_**
>  25 Fallen trees causing change in route (5) – **STEER***

Comment: That is, of course, correct. On 3D, I think the answer should be the one with the wordplay first, though. I agonized over this, and thought my phrasing forced this, but definitely open to correction if you disagree. Hope you enjoyed!

Comment: @JeremyDover Ah, I see what you mean. I've swapped those in the answer now. I think it could be interpreted either way, I seem to recall having seen those 3 words as an indicator at the start of the clue somewhere. 20 down was the toughest one for me here. I like how you used the Mystic there for both the Boston-themed surface and the particularly tricky definition. All in all a very nice puzzle!

Comment: Thanks Jafe! I definitely see your point about either interpretation on 3D...but no harm either way. Glad you liked 20D, that was my favorite too! Well, that and 12A...I struggled to clue it, and then the topical surface just fell out.

Comment: Your explanation for 25D has the wrong answer in it;  I'd edit it myself but it's one character too short.

Comment: Why is 4A "speous" broken down? Also, what is the definition part of 8D?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I'll be happy to edit. What's the correct parsing there?

Comment: @justhalf Added an explanation to 8 down. Speous is "spouse" anagrammed (broken down).

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that meaning of that word. And I thought broken down meant you split it but not anagram it. Nice work.

Comment: And for 25D, your image and your text don't match. Maybe that's what Michael is referring to.

Comment: @justhalf Ahh, now I see! Fixed now.

Comment: In 21D, where do you get `-ho` from `Hawai'ian Don departed`?

Comment: @justhalf Hawaiian musician [Don Ho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Ho)

Comment: Wow, the amount of knowledge required to answer this puzzle is so high.